# Creating Google GeoChart async

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to put a GeoChart in my app but I don't want to create it when the DOM is loading.
I only want to render after a user interaction. I have loaded the google.visualization library including the GeoChart and CoreChart packages.

When I am loading the Chrome console google.visualization.arrayToDataTable and google.visualization.GeoChart are missing! The same code works when executing everything on DOM load.

Any hints on how to properly the load the lib?

Comment: Can you include the code that has gotten you this far?

Comment: I add a very dirty hack. I craeted a hidden div 1px wide so upon page load I created the GeoChart (with an empty array). After that I had access to everything I needed (in google.visualization) at any time time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included these two lines:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
```

But instead of making the callback drawRegionsMap, call some other function that handles when you load your chart. Hope that helps.